# Formatting $_GET for mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my php code:

```
//Code for fetching content (view-me.php)
<?php
include('connect.php');
$head_title=$_GET['title'];
//echo $head_title;
$head_title=$mysqli->real_escape_string($head_title);
//echo $head_title;
$query="select title,content,pub_date from news where title='$head_title'";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
if($result){
    while(list($title,$content,$date)=$result->fetch_row())
    {
        echo '<div id="post_my_head">';
        echo "<h1>".$title."</h1></div><br />";
        echo '<div id="posted_date_time">'.$date.'</div>';
        echo '<div id="post_my_content"><p>'.$content.'</p></div>';

    }


    $mysqli->close();
}
else
    {
        echo "Query failed";
    }

?>

//Code for printing content:(news.php)
function print_content()
{
    include('connect.php');
    $query="select title,content,url,pub_date from news order by pub_date desc";
    $result=$mysqli->query($query);
    while(list($title,$content,$url,$date)=$result->fetch_row())
    {
        echo '<div id="post_my_head">';
        echo "<h1><a href='view-me.php?title=".addslashes($title)."' id='my_post_link'>".$title."</a></h1></div><br />";
        //$new_title=str_replace(" ","-",$title);
        //echo "localhost/".$new_title."/";
        echo '<div id="posted_date_time">Published:'.$date.'</div><br /><br />';
        echo '<div id="post_my_content"><p>'.$content.'</p></div>';
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
print_content();
```

It works perfect for most of the queries.It fails when the $head_title has a single or double quotes.I tried using addslashes in news.php but it doesn't work.

The code fails when the $head_title is something like "America's Freedom".In this case $title becomes "America" and the rest of the string gets truncated automatically.So the url becomes something like "localhost/?title=America" instead of "localhost?title=America's Freedom".The data type used in mysql is text.The code works perfect for all queries without single or double quotes.

Comment: Why are you identifying news by title? Use numeric identifiers instead of titles, the way you did is completely wrong.

Comment: Why not use a prepared statement? given you're already using `mysqli_*` it's the best way to go

Comment: @S3Mi if you use numeric identifiers - would that not only work if the GET parameters were the same every time?

Comment: @S3Mi:Titles are more seo friendly than id's.@Elias: I am new to mysql queries.

Comment: If you pass titles in $_GET then it's same seo friendly as ID because parameters after "?" are mostly ignored. Use routing and generate URI with title AND with ID, title will be nice for SEO and ID will be nice for you identifying news. @Chris - I don't understand the question/issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the URL, URL-encode the value. For putting that encoded URL into HTML, HTML escape it on top:

```
printf('<h1><a href="view-me.php?title=%s" id="my_post_link">%s</a></h1>',
       htmlspecialchars(urlencode($title)),
       htmlspecialchars($title));
```

See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and urldecode for this to fix

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Jane & 'Tarzan'";
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT);
echo "<br />";
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<br />";
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

try htmlentities